# Can not run some time SQL query in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

This code is used to display the number of days sold by the month

```
public long getCountsOfQuery(String condition, Class outputclass) throws Exception {
  Session session = BuilderSession.getSession();
  return Long.parseLong(session.createSQLQuery(condition).uniqueResult().toString());
}
```

My JSP file is  :

```
<td><%= ho.getCountsOfQuery("select COUNT(*) from store_sales where date like '"+ fd.getPartDate(FormatDate.PART_YEAR)+fd.getPartDate(FormatDate.PART_MONTH)+"01"+"' ", object.getClass())  %></td>
<td><%= ho.getCountsOfQuery("select COUNT(*) from store_sales where date like '"+ fd.getPartDate(FormatDate.PART_YEAR)+fd.getPartDate(FormatDate.PART_MONTH)+"02"+"' ", object.getClass())  %></td>
....
<td><%= ho.getCountsOfQuery("select COUNT(*) from store_sales where date like '"+ fd.getPartDate(FormatDate.PART_YEAR)+fd.getPartDate(FormatDate.PART_MONTH)+"31"+"' ", object.getClass())  %></td>
```

After two runs cannot response query in hibernate.
Also, no errors occur at runtime.
Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean with "After two runs cannot response query in hibernate"?

Comment: please, don't use scriptlets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are not releasing connection.

```
  Session session = BuilderSession.getSession();
  Long result=Long.parseLong(session.createSQLQuery(condition).uniqueResult().toString());
 session.close();
return result;
```

Obviously you should wrap it in try-catch and close in finally block, but in general it shows you what you are missing.